# How to display variables in a MessageBox

Tags: python, python-2.7, wxpython, wxwidgets

I have this code:

```
 def OnClick(self, event):
     lan1 = self.a.Getvalue()
     lan2 = self.b.Getvalue()
```

Now I want to use a MessageBox, which should display the `lan1` and `lan2` values in it.

How can I do this?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/functions.html?highlight=messagebox#MessageBox):

```
wx.MessageBox('Lan1 = %s, lan2 = %s' % (str(lan1), str(lan2)),
              wx.OK | wx.ICON_INFORMATION)
```

Comment: Thank you forgot to convert it into str...thanks for the help